# Get function output to different HTML page by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, text, output

I have a function that gets all selected values from selects on my page as a text. I need a button that onclick opens new "blank" with different HTML page and puts output from my selectgetting function to text box on new page.

How to make that by JavaScript?

```
var w = window.open('form.html', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=500,height=950')
var box = w.getElementById('input_16');
box.value = "bodystyle: " + body + "<br>" + "color: " + color; 
w.focus();
```

this should work for changing the box text shouldn´t it? I first open second HTML in new window then i get its textbox by id and change its value. Why doesn´t it work?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using localstorage or cookies or query string?

Comment: didn´t try anything :D cause im JS noob. Writing here to get some hints how to do it

Comment: Probably easiest to append a querystring parameter to the url you're using for the new page then query that in the new page to populate the text input.

Answer (score 0):

to pass your dropdown value to the _blank page you could add it as parameter in URL.
Them read it with Javascript from url on next page and put it in your text box.

So:
1. Read the value
2. Add to URL
3. Read the value from url
4. Add value to textbox

Good luck.

EDIT: this does 1 and 2.

```
 <div>
<input type="button" value="click me" />
 <input type="text" id="input_16" value="input16" />
 </div>


<script>
 $(function(){ $("input[type='button']").on('click',function(){ var val = document.getElementById('input_16').value;  window.open('form.html&param1='+val, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes') })})
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2BejP/